# Unable to fix the by default blank page of cypress updated version

Tags: cypress, cypress-component-test-runner, cypress-intercept, cypress-custom-commands

[After updating the cypress to latest version i'm geting this error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DtE2d.jpg)

[However i added the testIsloation to false in cofigration file but I'm still getting this error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/um5Y2.jpg) 
can anyone please help